# How to build and run VR application developed in Unity on HP Omnicept Reverb G2?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, windows-mixed-reality, openxr

absolute VR dev newbie here.
As stated in the title, how can I "build and run" VR application developed in Unity on HP Omnicept Reverb G2 headset? In other words, how can I turn my Unity project into an `.exe` or apk (not sure what is the correct file format)? Then how can I load this `.exe` file into my HP headset and run it?
I have experience developing VR applications for Quest2, and I remembered building my Unity project into an apk, and then load it into Quest2 through Sidequest. However, I have no idea how I may do the same thing but with HP headset...Please help!!! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unity, you can choose to build for **Universal Windows Platform**, please refer to [Set up a new OpenXR project with MRTK - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/new-openxr-project-with-mrtk#set-your-build-target). Then refer [Using Visual Studio to deploy and debug - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-visual-studio?tabs=hl2#deploying-a-vr-app-to-your-local-pc) to deploy the application to the PC via Visual Studio, and run the application via [Windows Mixed Reality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/enthusiast-guide/install-windows-mixed-reality) on the PC. This document may be useful to you - [Unity development for VR - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/unity-development-wmr-overview).

Comment: Thanks! I setup the packages according to the instructions provided by MRTK. But I can't find the proper way to run the app in Omnicept in VS Code. Could you take a screenshot of the entry point (i.e. the last button one would press) to run the app in Omnicept or any windows headset? Thank you so much!!

Comment: Have you already deployed your application to your computer and use [Windows Mixed Reality Portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/enthusiast-guide/install-windows-mixed-reality) to connect your computer and VR device? If so, you should be able to find your application in the All Apps of the device.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that to run the application, you simply double click the .exe file on your desktop...I wasn't able to run the .exe file due to a problem in my own PC. I swicthed to another PC and everything works fine.